# Is there a Python function that checks if a generator is started?

Tags: python, generator

I try to define a generator function `mycount()` that can be reset with the generator function `send(0)` as in the example below. Everything works fine, except when I use `send(0)` on a new generator object that hasn't started yet. In this case it gives a `TypeError`. Is there any function that checks if the generator has started or do I have to catch the `TypeError` and create a new generator object with `mycount(0)` in such case?

```
def mycount(value):
    while True:
        v = yield value
        if v == None:
            value = value + 1
        else:
            value = v

g = mycount(3)
print(next(g))    # prints 3
print(next(g))    # prints 4
print(g.send(0))  # prints 0
print(next(g))    # prints 1
print(next(g))    # prints 2

g2 = mycount(3)
g2.send(0)
# TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To avoid sending a non-`None` value to a just-started generator, you need to call `next` or `send(None)` first.  I agree with the others that David Beazley's [coroutine decorator](http://dabeaz.com/coroutines/coroutine.py) (in python 3.x you need to call to `__next__()` function instead of `next()`) is a great option.  Though that particular decorator is simple, I've also successfully used the [copipes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CoPipes) library, which is a nice implementation of many of the utilities from Beazley's presentations, including coroutine.

Regarding whether one can check if a generator is started - in Python 3, you can use [inspect.getgeneratorstate](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getgeneratorstate).  This isn't available in Python 2, but the [CPython implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ddff866d820d/Lib/inspect.py#l1273) is pure python and doesn't rely on anything new to Python 3, so you can check yourself in the same way:

```
if generator.gi_running:
    return GEN_RUNNING
if generator.gi_frame is None:
    return GEN_CLOSED
if generator.gi_frame.f_lasti == -1:
    return GEN_CREATED
return GEN_SUSPENDED
```

Specifically, `g2` is started if `inspect.getgeneratorstate(g2) != inspect.GEN_CREATED`.

Answer (score 1):

As your error implies the `send` function must be called with `None` on a just-started generator
[(docs-link)](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator#generator.send).

You *could* catch the `TypeError` and roll from there:

```
    #...
    try:
        g2.send(0)
    except TypeError:
        #Now you know it hasn't started, etc.
        g2.send(None)
```

Either way it can't be used to 'reset' the generator, it just has to be remade.

Great overview of generator concepts and syntax [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf), covering chaining of generators and other advanced topics.

Answer (score 1):

In particular, you might find a way to use the `consumer` decorator described on p. I-131 of David Beazley's "Generator Tricks," to which J. Gwyn provided a link:

```
def consumer(func):
    def start(*args,**kwargs):
        c = func(*args,**kwargs)
        c.next()
        return c
    return start
```

I use something similar in my code.

Note that `if v is None` is preferred over `if v == None`.

Comment: This is really a nice solution, but it only works for generator functions that use this decorator. I prefer something that works on every generator. So, I use Rich Franks solution.

Comment: True, this solution is limited.  More significant IMO is that it changes the behavior of the generator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete implementation Python2 compatible routine, getgeneratorstate(gtor), with test code.

```
import unittest
import enum

class GtorState(enum.Enum):
    GEN_RUNNING ='GEN_RUNNING'
    GEN_CLOSED ='GEN_CLOSED'
    GEN_CREATED ='GEN_CREATED'
    GEN_SUSPENDED ='GEN_SUSPENDED'

    @staticmethod
    def getgeneratorstate(gtor):
        if gtor.gi_running:
            return GtorState.GEN_RUNNING

        if gtor.gi_frame is None:
            return GtorState.GEN_CLOSED

        if gtor.gi_frame.f_lasti == -1:
            return GtorState.GEN_CREATED

        return GtorState.GEN_SUSPENDED
    #end-def

def coro000():
    """ a coroutine that does little 

    """ 
    print('-> coroutine started')
    x =yield
    print('-> coroutine received ', x)


class Test_Coro(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_coro000(self):

        my_coro000 =coro000()
        self.assertEqual( GtorState.getgeneratorstate(my_coro000), GtorState.GEN_CREATED)

        next(my_coro000)  # prints '-> coroutine started'
        self.assertEqual( GtorState.getgeneratorstate(my_coro000), GtorState.GEN_SUSPENDED)

        try:
            my_coro000.send(42)  # prints '-> coroutine received 42 
            self.assertEqual( GtorState.getgeneratorstate(my_coro000), GtorState.GEN_SUSPENDED)

            self.fail('should have raised StopIteration ')

        except StopIteration:
            self.assertTrue(True, 'On exit a coroutine will throw StopIteration')
            self.assertEqual( GtorState.getgeneratorstate(my_coro000), GtorState.GEN_CLOSED)
```