# How can I tell whether a generator was just-started?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I'd like a function, `is_just_started`, which behaves like the following:

```
>>> def gen(): yield 0; yield 1
>>> a = gen()
>>> is_just_started(a) 
True
>>> next(a)
0
>>> is_just_started(a) 
False
>>> next(a)
1
>>> is_just_started(a) 
False
>>> next(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> is_just_started(a)
False
```

How can I implement this function?

I looked at the `.gi_running` attribute but it appears to be used for something else.

If I know the first value that needs to be sent into the generator, I can do something like this:

```
def safe_send(gen, a):
    try:
        return gen.send(a)
    except TypeError as e:
        if "just-started" in e.args[0]:
            gen.send(None)
            return gen.send(a)
        else:
            raise
```

However, this seems abhorrent.

Comment: Is it allowed to modify inside the generator itself?  Is it allowed to decorate it?

Comment: it looks like `gi_running` indicates that the interpreter is actually currently running the code, so it's false between iterations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Python function that checks if a generator is started?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684908/is-there-a-python-function-that-checks-if-a-generator-is-started)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This only works in Python 3.2+:

```
>>> def gen(): yield 0; yield 1
... 
>>> a = gen()
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getgeneratorstate(a)
'GEN_CREATED'
>>> next(a)
0
>>> inspect.getgeneratorstate(a)
'GEN_SUSPENDED'
>>> next(a)
1
>>> inspect.getgeneratorstate(a)
'GEN_SUSPENDED'
>>> next(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> inspect.getgeneratorstate(a)
'GEN_CLOSED'
```

So, the requested function is:

```
import inspect

def is_just_started(gen):
    return inspect.getgeneratorstate(gen) == inspect.GEN_CREATED:
```

Out of curiosity, I looked into CPython to figure out how it was determining this...  Apparently it looks at `generator.gi_frame.f_lasti` which is the "index of last attempted instruction in bytecode".  If it's `-1` then it hasn't started yet.

Here's a py2 version:

```
def is_just_started(gen):
    return gen.gi_frame is not None and gen.gi_frame.f_lasti == -1
```

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow. Even better, it looks like this is [well-defined](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getgeneratorstate).

Comment: What is `GEN_RUNNING` good for? the doc says"if it is currently being executed by the interpreter", but I thought that's nonsensical because of GIL?

Comment: @cat Phrasing is a bit weird. The generator could be running but blocked by IO (e.g. [this gist](https://gist.github.com/earwig/c6277887f872ffd1785f9a67fc629d7c)). I suspect it will also happen if the generator is in the middle of execution but deferred by the scheduler.

Comment: @cat: Maybe you're *in* the generator. It'll also be the state of generators running in other threads, whether or not those threads are blocked by the GIL.

Comment: @cat: `def g(): yield inspect.getgeneratorstate(x)` `x = g(); next(x)`

Comment: Is this guaranteed outside of CPython - for instance PYPY or other Python implementations - or does this boil down to CPython implementation detail.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 - I don't know.  The 3.2+ version of the method is in the documentation of `inspect` so it should work in pypy3 and other implementations that support 3.2+ (otherwise it should be considered a bug in their implementation).  The py2 version makes use of something I found in the CPython source and I'm not sure if it's documented as being part of the language (you'd have to search the PEP's to see if it's defined there).

Answer (score 26):

Make a new generator which simply yields from your generator of interest.  **It sets a flag once the first value has been consumed**.  Afterwards, it can simply use `yield from` for the rest of the items.

Use the substitute generator as a drop in replacement for the generator you're interested in monitoring the "is_just_started" state.

This technique is non-intrusive, and can be used even on generators for which you have no control over the source code.

Comment: This technique has the advantage that it will work on all Python versions - including Pypy for instance.

Answer (score 5):

You may create a iterator and set the flag as the instance property to iterator class as:

```
class gen(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        self.num, self.nums = 0, []
        self.is_just_started = True  # Your flag

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    # Python 3 compatibility
    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()

    def next(self):
        self.is_just_started = False  # Reset flag with next
        if self.num < self.n:
            cur, self.num = self.num, self.num+1
            return cur
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

And your value check function would be like:

```
def is_just_started(my_generator):
    return my_generator.is_just_started
```

Sample run:

```
>>> a = gen(2)

>>> is_just_started(a)
True

>>> next(a)
0
>>> is_just_started(a)
False

>>> next(a)
1
>>> is_just_started(a)
False

>>> next(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 19, in next
StopIteration
```

To know the difference between *iterator* and *generator*, check [*Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776829/difference-between-pythons-generators-and-iterators)

Comment: That's not a generator.

Comment: @wim: Indeed True. Sorry for my terminology *class based generator*, correct word should have been *iterator*. Updated answer.