# Python and looping through a generator once per frame

Tags: python, loops, return, generator, yield

So I am implementing a pathfinding algorithm in python and I want to look how each iteration looks like. So I made it a generator that will yield every intermediate result up until the final result which will end with a `return` statement.

I made a quick pygame (because I am not aware of python libraries yet, so it was the simplest for me to make a grid and color the cells) program to visualize everything. Every frame makes an iteration on the algorithm and updates a variable `result = next(alg)`. The problem is when the algorithm ends, It still tries to go next. I was wondering if there is a way around this **other than catching the stopiteration error**. The best for me would be something like `if not alg.over() : result = next(alg)`, but I found nothing on the internet. Is there something like that that I can use? Thank you !

Comment: The correct way is to catch the exception. There is no other way. You can iterate through the items in a `for` loop, but internally, that is also going to catch the exception.

Comment: Perfect then! I just thought there was a more pythonic way than dealing with the exception. Also performance-wise I thought that an if statement would be faster than a try-catch block for every frame. That's also why I can't use a for statement : I need to make one iteration per frame. 

Thank you, I will just use the try-except method.

Comment: [How can I tell whether a generator was just-started?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41307038/953482) talks a little bit about inspecting the state of a generator, including whether it's closed. But using `inspect` to look at private-ish attributes isn't particularly idiomatic, so it's more of a curiosity here than a production-quality solution.

Comment: On second thought, `inspect.getgeneratorstate` can't tell you the answer to "has this generator yielded its final value, and the next call to `next()` will raise a StopIteration?" because that would require solving the Halting Problem. The best it can do is answer "has this generator already raised StopIteration at least once?"