# How to check if generator was used?

Tags: python, generator, yield

Is it possible to know if generator was used? i.e.

```
def code_reader(code):
   for c in code:
        yield c

code_rdr = code_reader(my_code)

a = code_rdr.next()

foo(code_rdr)
```

After `foo` call I would like to know if `.next()` was called on `code_rdr` by `foo` or not.
Of course I could wrap it by some class with a counter for `next()` calls. 
Is there any easy way to do so?

Comment: how about getting the index of the item the `foo` would return like `code.index(foo(code_rdr))`? I know, it is not perfect in case of duplicates but its something

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: but `foo` is likely a blackbox...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Python function that checks if a generator is started?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684908/is-there-a-python-function-that-checks-if-a-generator-is-started)

Comment: Another relevant dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307038/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-generator-was-just-started

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem meaning?... ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used idea from attached possible answers, bellow is redefined `code_reader` function:

```
def code_reader(code):
length = len(code)
i = 0
while i < length:
    val = (yield i)
    if val != 'position':
        yield code[i]
        i += 1
```

by using .send('position') on I would have know position of next item to be generated, i.e.

```
a = code_reader("foobar")

print a.next()
print a.send('position')
print a.next()
print a.send('position')
print a.send('position')
print a.next()
print a.send('position')
```

output:

```
0
0
f
1
1
o
2
```

Answer (score 10):

Python 3.2+ has [`inspect.getgeneratorstate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#current-state-of-generators-and-coroutines). So you can simply use `inspect.getgeneratorstate(gen) == 'GEN_CREATED'`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> gen = (i for i in range(3))
>>> inspect.getgeneratorstate(gen)
'GEN_CREATED'
>>> next(gen)
0
>>> inspect.getgeneratorstate(gen)
'GEN_SUSPENDED'
```

Comment: it solves it in some special case when generator was not used pre <code>foo</code>. In my use case code_rdr will be already started.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, it sounds like a different question though, if you're saying `next()` has already been called?

Comment: @www Ok, well you could compare the `return` value of `inspect.getgeneratorlocals()` before and after calling `foo` but it won't work in all cases (like if your generator is `(c for c in 'aaa')`). Anyway, I suggest you ask this as a new question with a different title etc, it's a rather different question and you'll get more attention that way